# "Declaring a public let for an internal class" - Swift

Tags: swift, gps

I'm trying to make a app that uses GPS and below is my class for the GPS Controller. My tuple for latitude and longitude gives a compiler warning if I try to declare it as `public`.

```
class CoreLocationController : NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
var locationManager:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
public let ltuple: (latitude:Double, longitude:Double)?;
let location: CLLocation?
override init() {
    super.init()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    println("didChangeAuthorizationStatus")
    switch status {

    case .NotDetermined:
        println(".NotDetermined")
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() //Will use information provided in info.plist
        break

    case .Authorized:
        println(".Authorized")
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        break
    ...

    };
}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    //Important things
    let location = locations.last as CLLocation;
    let ltuple = (location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    //Printing
    let str = "didUpdateLocations:  "+String(format:"%f", location.coordinate.latitude)+String(format:"%f", location.coordinate.longitude);
    println(str)
    println(ltuple)
    }
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println(error)
}
};
```

When I tried to get rid of the second `let`, it gives me "Cannot assign `ltuple` to `self`". Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class is born with an `internal class` declaration implicitly, you just write `class SomeClass` but the code is really `internal class SomeClass`.

If you want to have `public` properties/functions/etc in your class, you must first declare your class as `public`.

`public class SomeClass`

`public let someImmutableProperty`

You can read everything there's to know about Access Control in Apple's Documentation: [The Swift Programming Language: Access Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)

I personally prefer this article which is very concise and simplifies the concept of [Access Control](http://www.codingexplorer.com/access-control-swift/).

Also you shouldn't use `;` in your Swift code, please consult this [Swift Style Guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#semicolons) for your reference.